# How to send data server (written in JAVA) to client (Written in Node.js)

Tags: java, javascript, node.js

I don't know this is possible or not.First I wrote client and server in Node.js and then both server and client wrote in Java those were worked as expected. Now I'm interested in connect Java server and Node.js client. But problem is cant send date between them

**This is server side code which is written in Java**

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;


public class MyServer {

    public MyServer() {
    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
        ServerSocket serverSocket= null;
        Socket socket =null;
        DataInputStream datainputstream=null;
        DataOutputStream dataoutputstream=null;
        try{
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8888);
            System.out.println("Listening ...");
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
    while(true){
        try{
            socket = serverSocket.accept();
            datainputstream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            dataoutputstream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            System.out.println("ip:"+socket.getInetAddress());
            System.out.println("message:"+datainputstream.readUTF());
            dataoutputstream.writeUTF("HELLO !");
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            if(socket!=null){
                try{
                    socket.close();
                }catch(IOException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if(datainputstream!=null){
                try{
                    datainputstream.close();
                }catch(IOException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if(dataoutputstream !=null){
                try{
                    dataoutputstream.close();
                }catch(IOException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        }
    }

}
```

**This is client side code which is written in Node.js**

```
 var net = require('net');
var HOST = '127.0.0.1';
var PORT = 8888;
var client = new net.Socket();
client.connect(PORT, HOST, function() {
        console.log('connected to: ' + HOST + ':' + PORT);
        client.write('Data comming from client...');

});
client.on('data', function(data) {
        console.log(data.toString());
        //client.destroy();
});
client.on('close', function() {
        console.log('Connection closed');
});
```

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is that you're having.  There is no reason why a Node.js client cannot communicate with a Java server; what is happening when you try?  Why do you think that you can't send a date between then?

Comment: No no  when connected it in server side it just show ip:127.1.1.1( System.out.println("ip:"+socket.getInetAddress());) there is nothing showing after that

Comment: @user3553031 Can you run this one and give any suggestion on this.It really helpful for me ..

Answer (score 2):

Your server (Java) is expecting a message from the client before it sends anything.  It will block until it receives such a message.  Since the server seems to not receive this message, either the client is not actually sending its message (ie, it's queueing it until it receives more data to send), or the server is expecting to receive more data.

The documentation for `DataInputStream.readUTF()` claims that it expects length-prefixed strings.  That's not what your client is writing.  The server is probably interpreting the first two bytes of your string as a length, then trying to read that many bytes of data,  Since there isn't that much data available, it's going to wait for more from the client.  Try using `BufferedReader.readLine()` instead, and make sure that your client is sending a newline at the end of its output.

If that doesn't work, try finding a way to flush the socket on the client side.  I don't know Node.js, but a quick skim of the documentation suggests that `socket.end()` might help, although that won't work if you need to send more data later on.

Comment: Really thanks for your comment about this.Because I found errors and correct those things and eventually it works.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for this

**Server side code**

```
 import java.io.DataInputStream;
 import java.io.DataOutputStream;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.net.ServerSocket;
 import java.net.Socket;
 import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
 import java.io.*;

public class MyServer {

public MyServer() {

}
public static void main(String args[]){
    ServerSocket serverSocket= null;
    Socket socket =null;
    BufferedReader datainputstream=null;

    try{
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8888);
        System.out.println("Listening ...");
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try{
        socket = serverSocket.accept();

    }catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("can't listen given port \n");
            System.exit(-1);
    }
    try{
        datainputstream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

        System.out.println("ip:"+socket.getInetAddress());
    }catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("can't read File \n");
            System.exit(-1);
    }

        try{


            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while((line=datainputstream.readLine())!=null){
                sb.append(line+"\n");
            }
            datainputstream.close();
            System.out.println("message:"+sb.toString());

        }catch(IOException e){

            System.out.println("Cant read file \n");
        }finally{
            if(socket!=null){
                try{
                    socket.close();
                }catch(IOException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if(datainputstream!=null){
                try{
                    datainputstream.close();
                }catch(IOException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }

}



   }
```

here is the my client

**Client side code**

```
var net = require('net');
var client = net.connect(8888, 'localhost');
client.write('Hello from node.js');
client.end();
```